# PHP mail(): Как прикрепить pdf-файл к письму?

Tags: php, email, pdf

Нужно, чтобы вместо message прикреплялся готовый файл с сервера и отправлялся mail(). Или есть другое решение ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Пример 1** демонстрирует работу с библиотекой PHPMailer. **Пример 2** использует mail() функцию напрямую. Пользуйтесь нужным вам примером

**Пример 1: как использовать PHPMailer:**

**[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)** - полнофункциональный модуль создания и передачи электронной почты для PHP. Метод `AddAttachment: $mail->AddAttachment("files/file1.pdf");` позволяет прикреплять файлы.

```
<?php

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // По умолчанию использует php "mail ()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "Чтобы просмотреть сообщение, используйте HTML-совместимый просмотрщик электронной почты!"; // optional, Закомментировать и протестировать.

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("files/file1.pdf"); // pdf file path
$mail->AddAttachment("files/fileթ.pdf"); // pdf file path

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Еще одна популярная библиотека **[Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html)**

**Пример 2: Использует [mail()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) функцию напрямую:**

```
$name        = "Название здесь идет";
$email       = "someone@gmail.com";
$to          = "$name <$email>";
$from        = "John Doe ";
$subject     = "тема ";
$mainMessage = "Привет,я сообщение с pdf файлом";
$fileatt     = "files/test.pdf"; // Расположение файла
$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "newName.pdf"; //Имя, которое вы хотите использовать для отправки, или вы можете использовать то же имя
$headers     = "From: $from";

// Открываем и читаем файл в переменную.
$file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
$data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

// Это прикрепляет файл
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
  $message = "Это multi-part сообщение в формате MIME․\n\n" .
  "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $mainMessage  . "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
  " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
  " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
 "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";

// Отправить письмо
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Письмо отправлено.";
} else {
    echo "При отправке почты произошла ошибка.";
}
```

Comment: во втором методе текст сообщения из $mainMessage не появляется в письме

Answer (score 0):

Код от Vanya Avchyan передает файл, но не передает текст сообщения.
Тот же, но полностью рабочий код тут: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556757/php-send-e-mail-with-pdf-attachment

3й с верха код